# Unknown not removable apps

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s, uninstallation

I have two apps: informacje and Czasoumilacz which I cant remove through Settings > Applications > Manage Applications. What's that and how do I handle the problem?

Comment: Is there an English translation for that second app name?  I presume the first has something to do with "information".

Comment: @JonnyP I think it's a music store app.

Comment: Yeah, looks like, but they are factory apps. xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sure you can remove the apps, you need to be rooted (see [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone)) to do so.  I recommend using [Titanium backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to uninstall them, you just load Titanium and then click on the app name to bring up a menu where you can uninstall it.